# it's not displaying the Option disabled [value]="null" selected> Choose User Types</option>

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddSelectaTopic"
    onchange="if(this.value==='') {this.style.color='#999'} else {this.style.color='#333'}" [(ngModel)]="user_type_id"
    (change)="TypeChange($event.target.value,access_id)" [disabled]="access_id == 1 || !access_id">
    <option disabled [value]="null" selected>Choose User Types</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of UserTypes; let i = index" [attr.value]="type.id" [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">
        <span *ngIf="access_id">{{type.name}}</span>
    </option>
    <option value="newType">New User Type</option>
</select>
```

I try changing the disabled value null selected but it's not displaying the "Choose User Types"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind a value of `null` to a select option, use `[ngValue]="null"`.  By using `[value]="null"`, Angular will always bind the value as a string.  So when the comparison is done you get a string value compared to null which is always false.  This is probably why your option is not being selected.

```html
<option disabled [ngValue]="0" selected>Choose User Types</option>
<option *ngFor="let type of UserTypes; let i = index" [ngValue]="type.id">
  <span>{{type.name}}</span>
</option>
```

- https://upmostly.com/angular/using-value-vs-ngvalue-in-angular

Comment: I tried it but it only shows on dropdown but not displaying the placeholder "choose user types"

Comment: Is the binding property `user_type_id` null?

Comment: this is the binding property I use in typescript "user_type_id: any = 0;"

Comment: @vince Also this `[attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null"` might interfere with the default selection.

Comment: For binding your default option to 0, check the update answer.

Comment: I tried removing that [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null' but still not displaying, It always shows inside the dropdown the "Choose User Types"

Comment: Update your loop binding to `[ngValue]` as well if you're binding to a number `[ngValue]="type.id"`.

Comment: now the error occurs, when I change the [ngValue]="null" to [ngValue]="type.id". T_T

Answer (score 0):

Use this `value=""` instead of `[value]="null"` to display the "Choose User Types"

```html
<select class="form-control" id="ddSelectaTopic"
    onchange="if(this.value==='') {this.style.color='#999'} else {this.style.color='#333'}" [(ngModel)]="user_type_id"
    (change)="TypeChange($event.target.value,access_id)" [disabled]="access_id == 1 || !access_id">
    <option disabled value="" selected>Choose User Types</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of UserTypes; let i = index" [attr.value]="type.id" [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null">
        <span *ngIf="access_id">{{type.name}}</span>
    </option>
    <option value="newType">New User Type</option>
</select>
```